# Emacs Shell: Reset Command

Tags: shell, emacs

In bash, I can clear the screen with the `clear` command and I can clear the whole "buffer" with the `reset` command.

I'm looking to accomplish the `reset` in Emacs `*shell*` terminal. Is there a command / keyboard binding for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. Found the answer on [this site](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellMode):

```
(defun clear-shell ()
   (interactive)
  (let ((old-max comint-buffer-maximum-size))
    (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size 0)
    (comint-truncate-buffer)
    (setq comint-buffer-maximum-size old-max)))
```

Then I also added a key-binding:

```
(global-set-key "\C-f" 'clear-shell)
```

Comment: I bind C-x h to 'mark-whole-buffer (which works in any mode/buffer) then just use C-w to kill the region. The above global-set-key will rebind C-f in all modes, not just your shell, which will hide the default C-f forward-char binding.